# Отобразить на off-line карте 30тыс меток

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Очень нравится приложение для Android "я.Карты" с его функцией offline показа карты выбранных областей. Хочется "вшить" в карту 30тыс меток, ездим далеко, интернета там нет. Обязательная кластеризация, на клиенте не знаю, но на сервере точно надо кластеризировать, нельзя сразу столько выдавать, все зависнет.

Вопрос, реально ли это, чтоб "я.Карты" ещё подгружал мой json... тогда надо веб сервер разворачивать на этом же Android устройстве.

Или без "я.Карты" обойтись, но как тогда показать offline карту на смартфоне.

Comment: Яндекс опубликовал MapKit, чтобы делать свои приложения поверх Яндекс.Карт: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapkit/